# Spring jQuery-File-Upload plugin error

Tags: spring, file, spring-mvc, jquery-file-upload

Im using the basic plugin of https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload and it doesnt work with spring, maybe the request params in the controller arent correct.

The jsp view:

```
$('#form-field-photo').fileupload({
            url: CONTEXT_PATH+'/settingsAdmin/setProfilePhoto',
            sequentialUploads: true
        });alert("");    

<input type="file" id="form-field-photo" name="upload" style="display:none" size="5000"/>
```

And the controller  is

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/setProfilePhoto", method = RequestMethod.POST)
 public void setProfilePhoto(MultipartHttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception{

}
```

The code reachs the alert so the plugin is correctly added i think.
Point it out that the multipart resolver is properly declared:

```
<bean id="multipartResolver" class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver">
    <property name="maxUploadSize" value="250000"/>
```

Comment: What is the error you are getting?  404 not found would indicate your request wasn't mapped to a handler (your `@RequestMapping`s are wrong).

Comment: I dont get any error, simply it doesnt submit anything and it doesnt reach the controller but doesnt crash

Comment: You have to be getting something back, at least a 200 OK. Can you use Chrome's dev tools or Firefox's FireBug and see what gets sent/received for the file upload call?